# How to update a notification scheduled in Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

Well, there is a scenario where I have to schedule the notification on azure notification hub using .net SDK.

This notification can be updated/cancelled before the schedule.

.Net SDK has a method **CancelNotificationAsync** to cancel the schedule, but how can I update it? Should I have to cancel and create another scheduled notification?

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

There is no way to update a scheduled notification. You would simply have to cancel it and resubmit it anew.